# Converting Expression<Func<BaseType,object>> to Expression<Func<DerievedType,object>>>

Tags: c#

I have a situation where in, I would like to convert an `Expression<Func<BaseType,object>>` to `Expression<Func<DerievedType,object>>`
I am also open to other solutions as well for this particular scenario.

To demonstrate the problem, i have base class as following

```
public class PersonBase
{
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        Dummy.Method1(this,x=>x.Name);
    }
}
```

Derieved Class is defined as

```
public class Student:PersonBase
{
    public string School{get;set;}
}
```

The Dummy class and associated methods are defined as

```
public class Dummy
{

public static void Method1<TDestination>(TDestination value,params Expression<Func<TDestination,object>>[] selector)
{
    var destinationType = value.GetType();
    var selectorType = selector.GetType();

    Console.WriteLine("Destination Type : " + destinationType.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Selector Type : " +selectorType.ToString());


    var FinalMethodToCallInfo = typeof(Dummy).GetMethod("FinalMethodToCall", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    var FinalMethodToCallMethod = FinalMethodToCallInfo.MakeGenericMethod(destinationType);
    FinalMethodToCallMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { selector });
}

public static void FinalMethodToCall<TDestination>(params Expression<Func<TDestination,object>>[] selector)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Finally here");
}
}
```

The whole example is demonstrated in the Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tsXH9O).

Since the destinationType in Method1 is of Type Student and selectorType is of type Expression>, I get an exception when i attempt to invoke the FinalMethodToCall using reflection.

```
Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[PersonBase,System.Object]][]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Student,System.Object]][]'.
```

I am slightly lost here. One solution I could think of was to use `ExpressionVisitor` to replace the Expression Parameter Type from `BaseClass` to `DerievedType`.

But I was curious to know why, when calling the method from Base (and passing expression), I was pointing to two different types (Derieved and Base). Could someone guide me in understanding this behavior and also if there is a better solution than using ExpressionVisitor to replace the Parameter Type ?

PS: I cannot change signature of my Save Method.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes to generic methods as below.

Update `PersonBase` and make `Save` method to explicitly declare `T`.

```
public class PersonBase
{
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public virtual void Save<T>() where T : PersonBase
    {
        Dummy.Method1<T>(this,x=>x.Name);
    }
}
```

Update `Method1`'s first parameter to be `Object` like below.

```
public static void Method1<TDestination>(Object value,params Expression<Func<TDestination,object>>[] selector)
```

And call your `Save` with explicitly passing generic value like as follow.

```
(new Student{Name="anu"}).Save<Student>();
```

Comment: Karan, perhaps i should have been bit more clear, i cannot change signature of my Save Method in this case.